# How to deploy MySQL Workbench database with C# Winform Application setup?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, setup-deployment

I have developed a c# Win-Forms Application along with MySQL workbench database.
Application works very fine and also its setup also works fine.It properly installs in my PC and no problem occurs when working with application on my computer (on which it is developed).

But real problem occurs here when I move the applciation's setup to another PC. It  also installs there well and run properly but one huge problem occurs.

"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts".

1-How to solve this problem.?
2-How to attach database with application setup to be moved any client computer?
3-Is it necessary that MySQL workbench must be installed in the client's computer ?

Comment: Installing MySQL can be a stand alone procedure, it does not have to be connected with your setup file. You can manually install MySQL on any of your new clients prior to the installation of your program.

Comment: Very broad topic.  You have two problems:  1) installing the MySQL engine; 2) creating the database.  You could couple the engine install with your app install, but it's really a separate thing.  The database itself needs to be created once the engine is in place.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html

Comment: @DonBoitnott dear I know how to install MySQL but I didnot know the answers of above questions.